# InvalidByteSequenceError in a ruby/rack web app with chinese characters

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, rack

In my Ruby/Rack app I have static characters from Chinese and Japanese, in the ruby code and HTML views. When I'm running my app, I get an exception:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError at /
/my_app/index.html.erb is not valid US-ASCII
```

It happens only on a production server, on locally -- not. 
My local machine -- Linux, remote server -- FreeBSD.

I've tried "save with encoding --> utf-8" but it didn't help.

I'm not using encode/decode function in ruby code -- those characters are just statically embedded in my files.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which versions of ruby do you use on production/dev machines?

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with String input encodings. Strings you receive via `params` for example.

I had to enforce the encoding to UTF-8 via:

`"Some String".force_encoding("UTF-8")`

which stopped the error messages.